# How do I deploy BackgroundService?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a BackgroundService, how do I deploy this? I couldn't find any documentation about deploying a Worker project type.

I also have a WebAPI project that I deploy in IIS. I tried adding the Worker project to my WebAPI project, but my BackgroundService implementation isn't running - which I assume because the BackgroundService isn't meant to be ran in IIS? But it runs if I F5 in Visual Studio...

Edit: The BackgroundService was running just fine, I was being an idiot. I forgot IIS runs under a different account, so my DB connection string cannot use IntegratedSecurity. It runs fine after I change the string to a user credential.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
```

What are my options when it comes to deploying a BackgroundService?

Comment: how about baked the background in WebAPI already ? [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) should help. If a separation was needed, then make it separate project then just deploy it normally. And in case we don't need Http communication with the background one, even a simple console work.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can bake the background service together with my WebAPI. My question was why it did not work, when I stupidly forgot IIS runs under different account so I can't read anything from my db. Anyway, I'm curious now what's the difference running it together with my WebAPI vs running separately as Windows service.

Comment: `Windows service` as the name indicated, tied to window. I was not tend to use it since we just cross the dawn of containerize. Bake the background in your webAPI would be able to run pretty much anywhere, at the cost of just a few `Task` load (I don't know how frequent and heavy we tend to use, so... just estimation). Personnally, I deploy one pod as WebAPI and one for the background(so, request to change some setting over http was enable), and those two was not tied together. Best of both world

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if we wants to deploy the background service, I suggest you could try to deploy it as a windows service.

About how to make the asp.net core application to run as a service, you could refer to below steps:

In CreateHostBuilder of Program.cs:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
```

Then you could deploy it and run this application as a windows service. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Do you know if there's any difference running my background service in the same application together with my API, vs running it separately as Windows service? I don't have any specific reason, but just curious what's the pro/cons of doing it this way.