# Creating a Windows Background Service Installer for a C# Project Similar to MongoDB's Installer

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm transitioning from a JavaScript background to working on a C# project. This project initially began with the "web app" template in Visual Studio. Eventually, we decided to separate our project into distinct front-end and back-end components. The front-end is being developed in JavaScript by a dedicated team, using TauriJS, which conveniently includes a built-in installer.

For the back-end part, which is developed in C#, I am looking for a way to create an installer that functions similarly to how MongoDB installs its Windows background service. Specifically, I need the installer to ensure that, once installed, our C# back-end service automatically starts whenever the operating system boots up.

I've attempted to find guidance through resources such as a Stack Overflow question ([How do I deploy BackgroundService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69453265/how-do-i-deploy-backgroundservice)) and Microsoft's documentation on hosting and deploying a Windows Service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). However, I find myself overwhelmed by the apparent complexity and the extensive changes and configurations that seem to be required for our C# code.

Could anyone provide a more streamlined explanation or a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that minimizes the need for significant modifications to our existing C# project.

Comment: There are no "background services", just services. All installer technologies can install services since 2000 (and earlier). As for complexity, the deployment guide you linked to uses a *single PowerShell command only* to install the service, `New-Service -Name {SERVICE NAME} -BinaryPathName "{EXE FILE PATH}" -Credential "{DOMAIN OR COMPUTER NAME\USER}" -Description "{DESCRIPTION}" -DisplayName "{DISPLAY NAME}" -StartupType Automatic` and another to start it. The rest of the article talks about packaging and publishing applications, not installing a service.

Comment: `similarly to how MongoDB installs its Windows background service` what does that mean? MongoDB isn't doing anything special. No matter the application, in the end the same APIs are used. Is the real question perhaps how to register the service through an `--install` parameter instead of using a `New-Service` or `sc create` ?

Comment: I need it to be an installable paid service for regular users of PCs, so I can't have the user open the terminal to install the service, what I meant by mentioning MongoDB is that once it is installed you will always find it if you open the task manager under the background tasks @PanagiotisKanavos you wont see it as open software on task manager

Comment: You don't understand what a Windows service actually is. Acquire that understanding via research and experimentation, **before** suggesting that a Windows service won't do what you need.

Comment: So what is the name of what I am actually needs? @IanKemp

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a [package installer project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components?view=vs-2022#create-an-installer-package-windows-desktop-1). You will create a new project (using this template) in your solution. This project will package your app into a single *.msi or *.exe setup file which you can then distribute to end users.

Comment: You can configure your installer to execute commands to register your Service and configure startup options as part of the installation process. It does take some time to learn all of this, if you have never done this before, but it is not complicated.

Comment: @Alex one more question, dotnet core is said to be also running on linux, and mac, how can I create and installer for these as well ?

Comment: I don't know of the top my head as I have never done this before. Searching for "linux app distribution for .net apps" should get you started. (One of the first links that show up: https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/g1xi3o/how_would_i_distribute_a_net_core_web_app_to_be/)

Comment: Please note that Windows Service will not run in Linux ;)

Comment: @Alex then what will work?

Comment: I never developed anything for Linux or cross platform, but my guess is that a regular console app should work across platforms without too much drama.....